# Sending characters on USB port of android phone

Tags: usb, uart

My android device mmx a89 ninja phone does not have a host controller.I wish to develop an application which will simply send ascii values of characters,that I press,at the USB port of my device.

Is it possible without rooting the device?

The ascii values need to be sent in the simple UART format.

Start bit--->Data--->Stop Bit

or normal USB format also might do if it could be converted to UART using USB to serial converter

Answer (score 0):

Let's first take a step back. Since you're not a host controller, your USB port will be connected to one (possibly via a hub, but tha's just plumbing). That host controller you're connected to will not expect "start bit -> data -> stop bit". That's in violation of USB spec.

A USB-to-serial converter appears like it could work. After all, it takes a serial USB datastream, strips off USB overhead, and adds start&stop bits. But a USB-to-serial converter in general expects to talk to a host controller.

What you'd need is therefore a smart peripheral. E.g. a Raspberry Pi does have both a USB host controller and a UART.

Comment: But isnt there some way by which I could access the USB port of my device without any host?

Comment: @Abhishek: No. USB ports just aren't designed for that. Typically they're connected directly to the SoC, which has dedicated USB circuitry. I.e. the USB behavior is driven by hardware.